# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/491/design-for-drupal-answers).

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

http://sstatic.net/drupal/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/drupalmeta/img/favicon.ico

If you see any CSS bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: wow, the design looks very nice!

Comment: Does this mean we are officially out of beta and the new reputation levels are in place?

Comment: @MPD Looks like it, I no longer have permissions I used to such as vote to close

Comment: @MPD yes this means the site is now officially out of Beta. [also see](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/497/what-will-happen-to-the-privileges-when-drupal-answers-is-not-anymore-in-beta-pha)

Comment: Thank you for all your good work, and the time you took to understand what the design for DA could be.

Comment: Designs looks nice. Glad DA is out of beta

Comment: Good work guys, looks slick!

Comment: Nice to see the new design! Congrats to everyone

Comment: Only nitpick I have - the 'checkmark' icon for marking an answer is a bit smaller and harder to target with my mouse. Also, is there a way we could have a :hover state on that icon, the star, etc.?

Comment: Nice touch http://drupal.stackexchange.com/captcha

Comment: @tostinni thanks. [nicer touch](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/error)